# jQuery animation issue in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, google-chrome

I was animating an a element in jQuery using jQuery 1.3.2 and jQuery color plugin. I was animating the 'color' and 'backgroundColor' properties at the same time. In IE8 and FF it worked just fine. Chrome animated the mousehover color and then stopped. The background stayed the same and the mouseout did not undo the effect as it should have.

Chrome's developer tools said something about something being undefined. I know that I'm being somewhat vague here, perhaps this is a known issue?

EDIT - Code(, finally!):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(event){
    $(".nav a").hover(function(event){
      $(this).animate({"color":"#FFFFFF", "backgroundColor":"#3AB7FF"}, 900);
    },function(event){
      $(this).animate({"color":"#98DCFF","backgroundColor":"#FFFFFF"}, 900);
    });
  });
</script>
```

EDIT:

@Bernhard Hofmann - What do you mean "issues with the properties you've chosen"? Please elaborate.

Comment: If you could provide some code we might be able to help more.

Comment: I know, let me see what I can do...

Comment: I've also had an issue or two with jQuery under Chrome - I'm curious to see what the answer is here.

Comment: Can you post what version of Chrome you've tested in.  Your code seems to work fine for me in 3.0.195.24 and 3.0.195.38 on Win XP.

Comment: @Rob - I am on Vista Home Premium x64 and I think I was using version 4, gonna confirm and get back to you.

Comment: @Rob -confirmed - version 4.0.2xx.xxx

Comment: I'm with Mike now, I think the problem is something else.  Test this in your version: http://rvandam.com/animate-chrome.html.  I just checked 4.0.249.3 on Ubuntu and 4.0.249.64 on Win XP and both worked.  So unless the problem is specifically in 4.0.2 on Vista 64, it has to be some other aspect to what you are doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would seem that Chrome has a few issues with the properties you've chosen. I managed to get the animation working using mouse enter and leave events in Chrome. Here's the script and mark-up for those wanting to fiddle and have a go as well.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(event){
                $(".nav a").
                mouseenter(function(){$(this).animate({fontSize:"2em"}, 900);}).
                mouseleave(function(){$(this).animate({fontSize:"1em"}, 900);});
            /*
                $(".nav a").hover(function(){
                    $(this).animate({"color":"#FFFFFF", "backgroundColor":"#3AB7FF"}, 900);
                },function(){
                    $(this).animate({"color":"#98DCFF","backgroundColor":"#FFFFFF"}, 900);
                });
            */
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav" style="color:#000;background:#cfc;padding:2em 2em 2em 2em;margin:2em 2em 2em 2em;">
            <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010576/jquery-animation-issue-in-chrome" id="a1">StackOverflow</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you try with the color and background color properties please and let me know how it goes?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug with the color animation plugin with webkit browsers with their `rgba(r,g,b,opacity)` format for background color style.

The fix is simple, just add these lines in the appropriate place inside the `getRGB(color)` function of the plugin.

```
// Look for rgba(num,num,num,num)
if (result = /rgba\(\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*\)/.exec(color))
    return [parseInt(result[1]), parseInt(result[2]), parseInt(result[3])];
```

**EDIT:** Here is a working version with the fix http://jsbin.com/ekoli

Comment: Will this break other things? Why hasn't jQuery implemented this themselves?

Comment: @Moshe: I don't know if it breaks other things but even if it did, I'm pretty sure it won't break anything other than the color plugin itself. As for your second question, here's a list of bug reports for the color plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/issues/color?categories=bug

Comment: Worked for me on Chrome 5.0.342.5 dev in Ubuntu 9.10, without "breaking other stuff". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide some HTML? I tried out with Google Chrome 4 BETA on Mac OS and Chrome 3 on XP and it worked as intended.

The HTML I used is as follows

```
<head>
   <!-- These are my local jquery files. Use yours or the ones from Google -->
   <script src="/osr/javascript/dev/librarys/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/osr/javascript/dev/librarys/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(event){
         $(".nav a").hover(function(event){
            $(this).animate({"color":"#FFFFFF", "backgroundColor":"#3AB7FF"}, 900);
         },function(event){
            $(this).animate({"color":"#98DCFF","backgroundColor":"#FFFFFF"}, 900);
         });
      });
   </script>
</head>

<body>
   <div class="nav">
      <a>aighosvaovhaovuho</a>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your <a> tag is not complete and I think that may have to do with your success. change it to <a href="#">text</a>

Comment: It worked with an href just fine too. I suspect the error to be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, using jQuery.animate
Works fine in FF, IE 7 & 8

The code..

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery('.boxgrid.caption').hover(function(){
    var s = jQuery(".cover", this).stop(); 
        s.animate({width: "50%"},{queue:false,duration:300});                               
        jQuery(".cover", this).stop().animate({top: "180px"},{queue:false,duration:300});
    }, function() {  
        jQuery(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'260px'},{queue:false,duration:300});
    });

});
```

Produces:

> ERROR : (from chrome dev tool) :
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set
>   property 'width' of undefined

Comment: Exactly, except with color and backgroundColor! (I used slightly different code, but still, the same error while trying to do the same thing.) Could this be a Chrome bug, or a jQuery bug? (PS: This is technically not an answer, but I will borrow your code until I get mine up.)