# FIXED Text Getting weird when jquery animate fade on chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-animate

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

    $('#lol').hover(function() {

        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0.5});

    },function() {

        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1});

    });

});
```

**CSS**

```
#lol {
padding:20px; background-color:#FF0000; color:#FFF; font-size:15px; font-family:arial; width:300px; opacity:1; filter:alpha(opacity=100); position:relative;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="lol">text</div>
```

In Firefox and Internet Explorer it works fine but in Chrome, the text get weird on fade -- it look like that text is losing cleartype.

How can I fix it?

How it looks on fade: [Click to see](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg638/scaled.php?server=638&filename=imgbtq.png&res=medium)

**solution:** setting -khtml-opacity:0.99; and on mouseleave set it to 0.99. safari and chrome will work fine :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't fix it to be happy, but you do have options.

1. set webkit backface to hidden (same as below-ish, I also find this fixes many webkit display bugs) http://jsfiddle.net/FSkXL/
2. set the element to 0.9 instead of 1. This will prevent the text from changing (more consistent) by keeping it 'weird' http://jsfiddle.net/7YNhM/
3. you can use an image instead of text, png or svg, which means the text wont be editable webtext
4. canvas tag, tons of extra complexity

This is a fundamental part of how chrome renders text, and there just isn't a clean way around it.

Comment: My customers have been most happy with option 1 so far.

Comment: I got a question: 'set webkit backface to hidden', i didn't see any changes doint it.

Comment: check the fiddle. The text is 'bolder' before the fade without it. Then when the fade happens its not as bold. With the css in question the text is not as bold in both states.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me: the text doesn't change. Others can corroborate by looking at the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RZW9s/).

But I've encountered this bug before.  With animations, I've found, Chrome sometimes blurs or deforms the text (also does with with CSS3 transitions).  I think it's to do with your hardware  acceleration and graphics settings.

As pointed out by another user in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010576/jquery-animation-issue-in-chrome), Chrome seems to have difficulties with jQuery's hover() event, so perhaps you can use different methods:

```
$(function() {
   $("#lol").
   mouseenter(function(){$(this).animate({opacity:0.5}, 900);}).
   mouseleave(function(){$(this).animate({opacity:1}, 900);});
});
```

You can also have a shot at replicating the same functionality but with CSS3:

```
#lol
{
   opacity:1;
}
#lol:hover
{
   transition: opacity:0.5;
   -moz-transition: opacity:0.5; /* Firefox 4 */
   -webkit-transition: opacity:0.5; /* Safari and Chrome */
   -o-transition: opacity:0.5; /* Opera */
}
```

Comment: Try using CSS3 transitions, I've updated my solution with example CSS

Comment: i'm using this doctype: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: Look at my jsFiddle in my first line, if you're experiencing the same error there it's not to do with Doctype it's something which is hardware-based

Comment: well i'll try to fix it, if i found the solution i'll post, thanks for u help :)